# Where to buy Berserk in digital format?

Tags: merchandise, berserk

I want to start reading Berserk, but it seems like Dark Horse doesn't have the digital rights for the manga. Anybody know if there's another distributor that has the digital rights for this manga?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about where to buy a manga series.

Comment: @Happy I don't see why it should be off-topic then. http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/595/122

Comment: @looper I seem to have had a misunderstanding. I am retracting my close vote.

Comment: I realized the source of my misunderstanding. I had read the merchandise tag wiki a couple of days ago: http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/742/99

Comment: Do you want english subbed manga or japanese ? As for english there are no E-Books available as of yet but in japanese there are plenty

Comment: English translated is what I'm looking for. I know Kanji but I don't think it'll allow me to understand this manga in Japanese.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of July 18, 2017, Dark Horse released the manga digitally!

Answer (score 1):

(I know you asked for digital, but at least it's available in some form...)

RightStuf started re-printing Berserk: [Berserk Manga Gets Reprinting](http://www.rightstuf.com/rssite/main/news/individual/?ForumThreadName=FT0000005631).

You can now buy it form their website: [Browse All Berserk Graphic Novels](http://www.rightstuf.com/rssite/facetedSearch/?search=berserk%20graphic%20novel#/?s=berserk%20graphic%20novel).

> **NOTE:** The volumes don't display in proper numerical order, make sure to page through the results to find volume #1.